# navigation breaking in mobile and tablet

Tags: css

I am using fixed layouts however when I see my layout in
android tablets and phones the layout is breaking for some
reason.

Please visit http://www.iamvishal.com/pureecn/

and notice the top navigation "open account,  customer support and select language"

In the desktop it looks fine however the top navigation breaks in mobile browsers.

I am suspecting its the margin them.

```
#main_links_list_1,#main_links_list_2,#main_links_list_3
{

 margin-right: 65px;
 position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much things are breaking because you have half of your layout "fixed" and the other half "fluid".
For example:

```
div.section {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 960px;          /*fixed*/
position: relative;
}

#main_links_container {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;       /*fluid*/
}
```

Also note that when no width is set for an element, the default is auto.

Open your site on a desktop and try resizing the browser window you will probably see the same issue that you're seeing on mobiles and tablets.

If you really want to avoid media selectors you could try changing this-

```
html, body, #page {
height: 100%;
}
```

To something like this-

```
html, body, #page {
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a media query in your CSS for greater control on mobile devices-

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #main_links_list_1,#main_links_list_2,#main_links_list_3
    {
    margin-right: 15px; // reduced amount for mobile devices and tablets
    position: relative;
    }
}
```

Ensure this is BELOW the current CSS otherwise it will get overridden

Comment: however there are many screen sizes in tablets and mobiles then I need to think of each screen size. I assumed if I used fixed layout I don't need to worry about this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of reasons your site could be off in mobile/tablet.

1 ==> Create a fluid layout for non-desktop
2 ==> Make sure your meta viewport is correct (include retina display and Android dpi)

3 ==> Optimixe your images for mobile
4 ==> beware of position:fixed on older iOs and Android devices. Does not work as expected.

Can you explain a little better what is breaking?

Comment: pls check the site www.iamvishal.com/pureecn

Answer (score 1):

You assumed wrong. YOu need responsive layout and not fixed! 
I suggest you take a look at zurb foundation v4.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be cause in the section **`Professional Solutions`** the last link is quite long, which breaks the layouts.

Try this in your css file:

```
#professional_solutions_list {
  max-width: 180px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

see the following screen to get what I meant (the red line is where your menu should reach, the blue line is where it is actually):

[image]

#### Update

The following state is the default one, with the problem as occurred in tablets, please notice the applied rules:

[image]

And this one after adding `max-width: 180px`, the problem is **solved**:

[image]

> I edit the css rules live, using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/)

### EDIT:

Upon your comment, I've checked the website again, please remove:

> width: 94%;

from  the div with the id: `secondary_links`

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem, when the browser window is re-sized, the layout is still broken.

Comment: thanks @apaul34208 for the comment, did you tried it out before downvoting ? see my edit, the proposed solution works just fine

Comment: Tried it using FF inspect, works to a point, but if you continue to narrow the window the same issue is visible. At least in FF.

Comment: Yeah, this is a fix for tablets as they have a big enough screen, you don't need to resize the firefox window to make it too small, but if we need a 100% support the design as a whole needs to be reviewed, either using separated CSS files, or make it all dynamic no fixed parts

Comment: Agreed. The `#professional_solutions_list` sticks out the farthest, but its certainly not the only issue here.

Comment: @apaul34208, yes indeed there will be others like that one, this is why I would advice using a completely responsive design for considering a mobile browsing

Comment: I agree completely. Going responsive from the beginning makes for a much easier design, in the long run. Less trouble shooting for different screen sizes and devices. Sorry about the down vote, I withdrew it, after seeing your point about it being a tablet solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although a responsive layout like zurb would be advisable - the quick fix lies in applying a

`min-width:` to your **page-wrapper** element